# Detect Android language support

Tags: android

I have developed application in Arabic language, And I want to support a wild rang of Android Devices. I want to detect if the device support Arabic to load it in Arabic or to load in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to *check* the configured locale you can use `<context>.getResources().getConfiguration().locale` (is a [java.util.Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)).

If you want to display the appropriate language resources based on the user's locale, the framework easily permits this.  You add your string.xml files to appropriate resource folders as documented in [this d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) article and the OS will use the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getAvailableLocales()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales%28%29) to get a list of available languages

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to check particular language support

```
if (isSupported(baseContext, "हिन्दी"))
    languageList.add("हिन्दी")
```

Just replace हिन्दी with arabic word

```
public static boolean isSupported(Context context, String text) {
        int w = 200, h = 80;

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
        Bitmap orig = bitmap.copy(conf, false);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        paint.setTextSize((int) (14 * scale));

        // draw text to the Canvas center
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;

        canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
        boolean res = !orig.sameAs(bitmap);
        orig.recycle();
        bitmap.recycle();
        return res;
}
```

[Refer full](https://lalitjadav007.blogspot.in/2017/09/check-language-is-supported-in-android.html)